# How to set alarm on selected weekdays(MonDay,Sunday) in ios. (Localnotification)

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

Hi friends i am doing a alarm application in that i had requierment Repeat alarm as selected days(Monday, tuesday,--). Once select Monday the alarm will fire on every monday. How to do this any buddy suggest me.

Advance Thanks.

[image: The Repeat had selected three days(monday,Thursday,Saturday)]

Answer (score 0):

When notification fire running this for get another 7 week days.

```
   NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy";

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate: localDate];

NSLog(@"date:%@",dateString);
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {


    // How much day to add
    int addDaysCount = i;

    // Creating and configuring date formatter instance
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];

    // Retrieve NSDate instance from stringified date presentation
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    //        NSLog(@"dateFormmater:%@",dateFromString);
    // Create and initialize date component instance
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setDay:addDaysCount];

    // Retrieve date with increased days count
    NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                       dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                       toDate:dateFromString options:0];

    NSString* weekDayString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate];
    NSLog(@"New date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
   //here check the selected week is in your Selectedweeks array then add notification
    }
```